# youtube_dl ModuleNotFound error on Heroku deployment

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I am trying to run my Discord bot on Heroku, but this error keeps popping up when I try to build. I think it has something to do with the module I am trying to download called `apafy`. I can install it without issues on my own PC, but I'm running into issues on Heroku.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
   1. heroku/python
   2. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
   3. https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> Python version has changed from python-3.9.10 to python-3.10.2, clearing cache
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.10.2
-----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
   Collecting discord==1.7.3
     Downloading discord-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
   Collecting PyNaCl==1.4.0
     Downloading PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (961 kB)
   Collecting youtube-dl==2021.12.17
     Downloading youtube_dl-2021.12.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
   Collecting apafy==0.5.6.1
     Downloading apafy-0.5.6.1.tar.gz (34 kB)
     Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
     Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ntv9wsqp
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/
     Complete output (16 lines):
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/apafy/pafy.py", line 48, in <module>
         import youtube_dl
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'
     
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
         from apafy import __version__
       File "/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/apafy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
         from .pafy import new
       File "/tmp/pip-install-bvs5njap/apafy_8fab839186e14eed8dceb069854e7599/apafy/pafy.py", line 51, in <module>
         raise ImportError(
     ImportError: pafy: youtube-dl not found; you can use the internal backend by setting the environmental variable PAFY_BACKEND to "internal". It is not enabled by default because it is not as well maintained as the youtube-dl backend.
     ----------------------------------------
   WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/d4/e2a27707c66a57b45b537bf77d0904cf912b4cf74f960fd54b75107207ac/apafy-0.5.6.1.tar.gz#sha256=abef75339d167e13737f0dd5f9f21947bb1a7dfbbdd9359995c10ec7b7f154dd (from https://pypi.org/simple/apafy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apafy==0.5.6.1 (from versions: 0.5.6.1)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for apafy==0.5.6.1
  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
  !     Push failed
```

Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
discord == 1.7.3
PyNaCl == 1.4.0
youtube-dl == 2021.12.17
apafy == 0.5.6.1
```

Comment: can you show us your requirements.txt file?

Comment: added it to the main post

Answer (score 1):

You should use `youtube_dl` (underscore) rather than `youtube-dl` (dash). When installing via `pip`, the package is referred to as `youtube_dl` (see [these docs](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/) for more details).

Comment: Changing `youtube-dl` to `youtube_dl` in the requirements file produces the same error.

Comment: It looks like the error message says that "you can use the internal backend by setting the environmental variable PAFY_BACKEND to 'internal'" -- have you tried setting that environment variable?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would do that. I tried creating a configuration variable on the settings page for my heroku app with 'PAFY_BACKEND' as the key and 'internal' as the value but it still gives me the same error when I build. Do I need edit anything in my code for this to work?

Comment: `pip install -r` [makes no guarantees](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) on the order in which dependencies are installed. Maybe try installing `youtube-dl` separately? It doesn't look like [apafy requires any dependencies](https://github.com/Azzy380/apafy/blob/main/setup.py), which seems really strange... might be worth filing an issue.

Comment: I don't know if you can manually install modules on Heroku. As far as I know, every time it redeploys, it redownloads all of the dependencies in the requirements file. The pafy module, which is what the apafy one is based on, installs fine even though the only difference between them is a couple line of codes to remove the tracking of likes/dislikes on Youtube. Have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I don't know Heroku super well, but can you change the commands that are executed (e.g. can you run `pip install youtube_dl`, then `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Again, I find it very odd that the `youtube_dl` dependency isn't mentioned anywhere in apafy's `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

i fix it by install library from my code because pafy needs youtube-dl installed before but heroku install all of them together so you can install apafy from your code

```py
import subprocess, sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])


try:
    import apafy as pafy

except Exception as error:
    print("Error: ", error)
    install("apafy==0.5.6.1")
    import apafy as pafy
```